# Calculate percentage completed at any given point of time based on estimated program end time in Java

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to implement progress of a long running process in Java. 
Based on the current logic I'm trying to calculate approximate time when the program going to end based on using the time taken for single unit of calculation. For ex: I'm running a invoice progress to be sent to multiple vendors and each invoice takes 10s. So based on this I'll calculate the time for rest of the pending invoices.

I'm keeping the start time in milliseconds.

```
long startmillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
long finishmillisforsingleVendor = System.currentTimeMillis();

long elapsedTime = finishmillisforsingleVendor - startmillis;

long approximateEndTime = elapsedTime/1000 * 25;// trying to calculate in seconds and multiply with 25 remaining invoices.
```

This is the part I'm not sure. How would I use this elapsed time for single invoice to derive my program end time.

```
long percentageCompleted = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000 / approximateEndTime ;
```

I'm trying to calculate the percentage at any given point of time to show the user how much has been progressed so far. I'm not sure if this the right way to go.

Thanks

Comment: Be careful of the pitfalls of division in integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the way you phrased your question, I suspect you're confusing a few terms. The percentage completed has nothing to do with elapsed time.

```
double percentComplete = 100.0*numberOfDocumentsCompleted/totalNumberOfDocuments;
```

Though, instead of a percentage, I would prefer a simple ratio:

```
double completionStatus = (double)numberOfDocumentsCompleted/totalNumberOfDocuments;
long elapsedMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startMillis;
long estimatedTotalMillis = (long) (elapsedMillis / completionStatus);
long remainingMillis = estimatedTotalMillis - elapsedMillis;
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I was little confused and taking a different approach. Simple solution as first one addresses my problem. Thanks.